# How to add pagination with limit for collections in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, pagination

I have filtered customer collection and showing in account navigation with one new custom link. upon clicking custom link on left nav i need to show collection on right side with pagination.

How this can be done? So far i am able to bring custom link on left nav and after clicking on it getting customer collection. How to add pagination to it with limit ?
Is that can be done. please advice anyone.

Comment: please review this https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-add-pagination-custom-collection/

Comment: can you explain in detail , i want to add pagination for my custom collection on customer account navigation. Already i bought the link on left nav with collection. how to show that in pagination?

Comment: Can you update your code to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Add code in your block file.

---

```
protected $_productFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function displayCollection()
{
    //get values of current page
    $page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    //get values of current limit
    $pageSize = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 10;

    // get your collection here for ex:- $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection() 
    $productCollection =  $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $productCollection->setPageSize($pageSize);
    $productCollection->setCurPage($page);
    return $productCollection;
}
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    if ($this->displayCollection()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'Your_module_namespace.Your_module_name.record.pager'
        )->setAvailableLimit(array(10 => 10, 15 => 15, 20 => 20, 25 => 25))->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
            $this->displayCollection()
        );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->displayCollection()->load();
    }
    return $this;
}

public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}
```

---

### Add code in your phtml file.

```
<?php
if ($block->displayCollection()) {
    $custommodel = $block->displayCollection();
}
?>
<?php if($custommodel && count($custommodel)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($custommodel as $value):?>
       //get your content here
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom custom-pager"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty" ><span><?php echo __('You have no any data.....'); ?></span></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is Your_module_namespace.Your_module_name.record.pager?
namespace and module_name i will replace with mine, what is record and pager?

Comment: any update about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method

```
$collection->setPageSize()
```

Comment: So it will show pagination this line? Please explain elaborately

Comment: just check vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/grid/extended.phtml

You will now what to do.

Comment: @AveshNaik what you mean You will now what to do???